# How to fetch string from a JSON array stored in Amazon Redshift column?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a database stored in Amazon Redshift and an array is stored in table column in JSON format.

How to fetch a string from array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using json_extract_path_text you can retrieve values from a column 
  [In Redshift database I have JSON in one column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL5kx.png) 
This query performs join and to get seperate column results.

```
SELECT json_extract_path_text(O._doc,'domain') AS Domain, 
       json_extract_path_text(P._doc,'email') AS Email
FROM   intelligense_mongo.organisations AS O
INNER JOIN    intelligense_mongo.people AS P
ON  json_extract_path_text(O._doc,'_id') = 
    json_extract_path_text(P._doc,'organisation_id')
Where 
json_extract_path_text(O._doc,'tools_name') = '%"WordPress"%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html):

```
select json_extract_path_text('{"f2":{"f3":1},"f4":{"f5":99,"f6":"star"}}','f4', 'f6');

json_extract_path_text
---------------------- 
star
```